# iOS - Gesture Recognizer translationInView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I use the following line of code in a pan gesture recognizer:

```
CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
```

If I move the associated processing to a long press gesture recognizer, there is not a translationInView method.

My question is, how can I get the same value for translation if using the long-press recognizer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply.  What I was really looking for was the computation for translationInView, which is different from locationInView.  I resolved this with the following code:

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint translation;
translation.x = location.x - viewStartLocation.x;
translation.y = location.y - viewStartLocation.y;
```

It does require me to track the starting location, which I didn't have to do with the pan gesture recognizer, but it seems to work well.  The rest of my code is centered around the translation rather than the location, so I was trying to avoid having to rewrite that other code just for the sake of consistency.

Thanks again for taking time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

For UILongPressgestureRecognizerv its not translation in view , it is locationInView .

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

switch (recognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   
}
```

Hope it will help you.