# Know if UICollectionView is scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is there a way in iOS to know if a UICollectionView is scrolling or not?

I want to know it because I'm loading in every UICollectionCell an image downloaded from the Web, but if the Collection View is big and I scroll until the end it starts downloading every image and if I change view I must wait that previous download, this slow down the app and is not cool, lol :D

Thanks and sorry for my English ;)

Answer (score 22):

As the previous post mentions, `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so I think you can just check a couple `UIScrollView` methods:

```
 BOOL isScrolling = (cv.isDragging || cv.isDecelerating);
```

Edit:
As the comment have mentioned, the API is now:

```
BOOL isScrolling = (cv.dragging || cv.decelerating);
```

Comment: Neat & clean approach. Nice answer.

Comment: Nice solution, though it doesn't work when `setContentOffset` is used.

Comment: Now it's `BOOL isScrolling = (cv.dragging || cv.decelerating);` right? I don't know if it changed at some point but that is what I'm seeing for `UIScrollView`.

Comment: This doesn't work if the collectionview is scrolling due to a call to setContentOffset:animated

Answer (score 5):

> For Swift

```
let isScrolling: Bool = colView.isDragging || colView.isDecelerating
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you out since UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061527/2916429

Comment: [Review Comment]:Please add synopsis here. Link-only answers are discouraged on SO