# How to cancel LongPressGesture so PanGesture can recognise

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I working with `UIGestureRecognizer` atm creating some map alike program.

My work require me to listen to both long press gesture and pan gesture separate, so each of them can do their own task.
But in one case, i need to listen to long press first to know which object is chosen. After that, when i begin to move my finger (without lift it up), that object will be move too. It kind of like drag a marker around in google map. But because my long press recognizer already fired, pan gesture recognizer didn't get fire until i tab on the screen again.

I tried something like

```
recognizer.enabled = NO;
recignizer.enabled = YES;
```

But it didn't help at all.

So i wonder if there anyway to cancel long press after it recognized (`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`) so pan gesture recognizer will be fire immediately when i begin to move. Or i have to use UIResponder to make it work ?

Thank for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to detect the pan gesture after the long tap. The only caveat is that, since `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` it does not have the `-translationInView:` that is so handy in `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

You can anyway do these calculations on your own by keeping track of where the touch has moved after the long press, as it will keep firing the action bound to the gesture recognizer.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382323/ios-gesture-recognizer-translationinview), it may help to calculate the translation with the long press gesture.

Comment: Thank for it. I didnt know that i can still use it to dect pan too. Set allowMovement to NO before. Have to modify code a little so other function accept UILongPress but all good now. Also i only need position in view not how much it moved so it much easier. But wonder if there any other way around it?